# find in string and replace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a string called **$body** and I'm trying to replace usernames in that string if they exist in users table and wrap them with anchor tag, the code works fine if only one user is in the string but if more than a username in the string my function blows specially if more than a user in the string and one is a real user exists in users table and another doesn't.

```
public function setBodyAttribute($body)
{
preg_match_all('/@([\w\-]+)/', $body, $matches);
    $users = $matches[1];

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (User::where('name', $user)->exists()) {
            $body = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href=/profiles/$1>$0</a>', $body);
        }
    }

    $this->attributes['body'] = $body;
}
```

Comment: You do the processing and place the result in `$newuser`, yet the next loop you process the value of `$body` again, so ignoring the previous results.

Comment: If more than one user then what you actually need??

Comment: @A.A Noman if more than a user, only the users exsist in users table change and leave the orhters

Comment: @Nigel Ren, that's correct but I'm stuck in this. what do you suggest?

Comment: I see an issue and unexpected result if `users`.`name` column is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/@([\w\-]+)/', $body, $matches);

$users=User::whereIn('name',$matches[1])->pluck('name')->toArray()

foreach($users as $user) {
        $body = str_replace('@'.$user, "<a href=/profiles/$user> 
        <strong>@$user</strong></a>", $body);
    }

    $this->attributes['body'] = $body;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```php
$newuser = preg_replace("/@{$user}/", "<a href=/profiles/$user>@$user</a>", $body);
```